# Using AND with multiple conditions for formatting google sheets/excel

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight a cell if 3 different conditions are met in 3 other different cells.

```
A       B        C        D
```

Highlight A: if B is greater than 5, C is empty, and D doesn't have a duplicate

When I use these formulas individually, they work:

```
=AND(b:b,>5)

=AND(isblank(c:c))

=AND(countif(A:A,A1)<2)
```

But when I combine them this way, they don't work:

```
=AND(b:b,>5),(isblank(c:c)),(countif(A:A,A1)<2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, if a value occurs multiple times, is there a formula to highlight all but the first occurrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Highlight A: if B is greater than 5, C is empty, and D doesn't have a duplicate

apply to range **A1:A**:

```
=(B1>5)*(C1="")*(COUNTIF(D:D, D1)<2)
```

[image: 0]

---

> Also, if a value occurs multiple times, is there a formula to highlight all but the first occurrence?

use shorter:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A1, A1)>1
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(A$1:A, A1, ROW(A$1:A), "<="&ROW(A1))>1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks! Both of the responses worked, and you gave the array formula too, so double thanks!

Comment: Can simplify the second one to =countif(A$1:A1,A1)>1

Answer (score 0):

The `AND` function requires additional brackets:

```
=AND((b:b>5),(isblank(c:c)),(countif(A:A,A1)<2))
```